# Concurrent Event Processing and Notification Handling in Distributed Systems

Tags: go, redis, concurrency

Right now I'm trying to solve a problem using golang kanlays and redis to store events

I have a task, sending notifications to a user. there are two events that come from the same `HTTP/S METHOD POST` request, `message.new` and `message.read`. When the `message.new` event comes in it should be added to the queue, but before adding it you need to check if there is such an event in the queue, otherwise you need to replace the old event with the new one. When `message.read` arrives, the event `message.new` must be removed from the queue if it exists. The `message.new` event will remain in the repository for 10 seconds after it is added, then it must be sent to the `notification` service.
I solved this problem as follows:

1. The **StorageHandler** struct:

   - It represents the main handler for processing tasks/events.
   - It includes the following fields:

     1. newEventChannel: A channel for receiving message.new events.
     2. readEventChannel: A channel for receiving message.read events.
     3. deleteEventChan: A channel used for communication between `handleMessageNewWorker` and `handleMessageReadWorker` to signal the deletion of an event.
     4. redisClient: The Redis client for interacting with Redis.
     5. deleteExpire: The duration after which an event is considered expired and sent to the notification service.
   - The **`ProcessTask`** method receives a task and based on its event type, sends the payload to the respective channels (newEventChannel
     or readEventChannel) for further processing.
2. **`handleMessageNewWorker`**:
   1. This method is executed as a background goroutine and handles `message.new` events.
   - It reads events from the newEventChannel and performs the following steps:
   Unmarshals the event payload into an `EventMessageRequest` struct.

   ```
    - Generates a unique key for the event in Redis using the getRedisKey method.

    - Sends the key to the `readEventChannel` channel to signal the deletion of any corresponding `message.read` event.

    - Checks if the key exists in the deleteEventChan channel. If it does, the event is ignored, and the loop continues to the next event.

    - Marshals the event into JSON format.

    - Stores the event in Redis using the key as the key-value pair.

    - Sets a timer using `time.AfterFunc` to trigger after the deleteExpire duration and send the event to the channel for notification if it hasn't been deleted.
   ```

   - This method uses a select statement to listen for events from the newEventChannel and includes a case for handling cancellation by checking the ctx.Done() channel.
3. **`handleMessageReadWorker`**:

   - This method is executed as a background goroutine and handles message.read events.
   - It reads events from the readEventChannel and performs the following steps:
     - Unmarshals the event payload into an EventMessageRequest struct.

     ```
        - Generates the key for the event in Redis using the getRedisKey method.

        - Deletes the event from Redis using the key.

        - Sends the key to the deleteEventChan channel to signal that the event has been deleted.
     ```
   - This method uses a select statement to listen for events from the `readEventChannel` and includes a case for handling cancellation by checking the `ctx.Done()` channel.
4. The getRedisKey method generates a unique key for an event based on the message ID and user ID. It concatenates the two values with a separator.

Overall, the code utilizes channels for handling different types of events (message.new and message.read), stores events in Redis, and uses timers to handle event expiration for notification. It ensures that if a message.read event arrives, the corresponding message.new event is deleted and not sent to the notification channel.

```golang
func (h *StorageHandler) ProcessTask(ctx context.Context, task *asynq.Task) error {
    event := task.Type()
    payload := task.Payload()

    switch event {
    case messageNewEventType:

        h.newEventChannel <- payload
    case messageReadEventType:

        h.readEventChannel <- payload
    default:
        log.Printf("Unknown event type: %s", event)
    }

    return nil
}

func (h *StorageHandler) handleMessageNewWorker(ctx context.Context) {
    h.mut.Lock() // Acquire the lock before modifying the readers count
    defer h.mut.Unlock()
    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case payload := <-h.newEventChannel:
                var event EventMessageRequest
                err := json.Unmarshal(payload, &event)
                if err != nil {
                    log.Printf("Failed to unmarshal event payload: %v", err)
                    break
                }
                key := h.getRedisKey(event.Message.ID, event.User.ID)

                h.readEventChannel <- key

                // Check if the key exists in the deleteEvent channel
                select {
                case k := <-h.deleteEventChan:
                    if k == key {
                        log.Printf("Event ignored: %s", event.Message.ID)
                        continue
                    }
                }

                value, err := json.Marshal(event)
                if err != nil {
                    log.Printf("Failed to marshal event: %v", err)
                    continue
                }

                err = h.redisClient.Set(ctx, key, value, 0).Err()
                if err != nil {
                    log.Printf("Failed to store event in repository: %v", err)
                    continue
                }

                time.AfterFunc(h.deleteExpire, func() {
                    // Check again if the key exists in the deleteEvent channel
                    select {
                    case k := <-h.deleteEventChan:
                        if k == key {
                            log.Printf("Event ignored: %s", event.Message.ID)
                            return
                        }
                    default:
                    }

                    h.channel <- &event
                })

                log.Printf("Event stored in repository: %s", event.Message.ID)
            case <-ctx.Done():
                return
            }
        }
    }()
}

func (h *StorageHandler) handleMessageReadWorker(ctx context.Context) {
    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case payload := <-h.readEventChannel:
                var event EventMessageRequest
                err := json.Unmarshal(payload, &event)
                if err != nil {
                    log.Printf("Failed to unmarshal event payload: %v", err)
                    break
                }
                key := h.getRedisKey(event.Message.ID, event.User.ID)
                if err := h.redisClient.Del(ctx, key).Err(); err != nil {
                    h.deleteEventChan <- key
                    log.Printf("Failed to delete event from repository: %v", err)
                }

                h.deleteEventChan <- key

                log.Printf("Event deleted from repository: %s", key)
            case <-ctx.Done():
                break
            }
        }
    }()
}
```

this solution is just an outline. But I plan to rewrite it and add a semaphore for synchronization between handleMessageNewWorker and handleMessageReadWorker methods.

Also:

1. buffered channels: Adding buffering to channels (newEventChannel and readEventChannel) can help handle event bursts without blocking senders. By specifying a buffer size for channels, senders can continue to send events without waiting for receivers to process each event.
2. Parallelism: Currently, goroutines are used to process message.new and message.read events simultaneously. This allows for parallel processing. However, I can further improve the concurrency by increasing the number of goroutines or by using the work pool model to process more events at the same time. This can be achieved by generating several goroutines to process events from the corresponding channels.

But I have some questions,

1. Should I use `Redis` as an event repository that delivers all events to `ProcessTask` or should I consider queues?
2. Perhaps someone can tell me if there is anything I can do to simplify the system I have described, perhaps I am missing something?
3. Are the goroutines and channels able to handle a high load, for event processing. I know that goroutines are very fast and take up very little memory, but still, there will be a lot of events coming in. Since I need to handle external api events, I need to handle a large number of events. A little description of how many events come, imagine you are writing a message to a friend, one of your message is two events just from you, the sender `message.new`, `message.read` . Then your friend opened the chat and starts reading and that's one event per message. If you have sent 100 messages that's 300 events in just one chat room